Weather infomation to show in notification section
I installed Ubuntu 24.04. The default system didn't include a weather application, so I installed GNOME Weather. This works well for me except it shows incompletely in the notification like what I shared here.

Is there any way to show the complete information or is there another application for weather?

Install Extension Manager and then navigate to and install OpenWeather
If not already installed you can install Extension Manager with
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager


Once installed click on the cog icon and select locations and make other adjustment as required.

This will place a weather icon on the systray next to the date/time.

Thanks! This is really good to know!

if that answered your question for you, please consider accepting it which will help others with the same question to find a suitable answer. Thanks.
